# Sitecore Content Tree Search Taking personalization_index Instead Of master_index

Tags: sitecore

I am facing the below issue related to the content tree search and I am unsure what is causing this issue.

I have solr as search my search. Whenever I am trying to search for something in my content editor search box  I am getting zero results. So when I checked the log files I came to know that it's taking personalization_index instead of master_index.

I have no customization related to this.

Note - If I do a search from the Sitecore desktop search box then it works and I am getting results as that's picking up the right index.

Answer (score 0):

check the `<index>` setting in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config`. It should point to `/sitecore`. 
`Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config` is located here: `\App_Config\Include`